# Anyone cannot plot using seaborn's relplot()?

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]
Hi all,
I have updated the latest seaborn version, however, when I typed into the relplot() function to plot the scatterpoint, it was shown as no attribute.

Any clue?

Comment: Please include the code and the error in the question, NOT an image. It really makes it difficult for anyone to reproduce your error. Also, include an example of the dataframe.

Comment: It looks like you have installed seaborn, but not reimported it afterwards. Always start with a fresh kernel after installing something.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that it works after restarting the session.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem. I ran this:

```
pip install --upgrade seaborn
```

then restarted the kernel; relplot() works fine now.